# Symfony 5.1 make:migration error "could not find driver"

Tags: mysql, symfony, makefile, migration, driver

When I try to make a `php bin/console make:migration`
I have this return :

```
  An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver  


In Exception.php line 18:

  could not find driver  


In PDOConnection.php line 37:

  could not find driver
```

I'm using internal server with server:run
I'm using PHP 7.4.11 and

`php -v` give me the good version php 7.4.11

My file doctrine.yaml have :

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
    # configure these for your database server
        driver: 'pdo_mysql'
        server_version: '5.7'
        charset: utf8mb4
        default_table_options:
            charset: utf8mb4
            collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
```

and my .env have :

```
# IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version, either here or in config/packages/doctrine.yaml
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:@127.0.0.1:3306/blog?serverVersion=5.7
```

My EXTENSIONS=pdo_mysql is active...

Comment: Is the pdo_mysql extension enabled/installed for your PHP?

Comment: what you see when you execute: `php -i | grep pdo` ?

Comment: Your Symfony app may use PHP with another php.ini than `php -v`. Can you check `phpinfo();` through your Symfony application?

Answer (score 0):

It may be late for you, but hopefully this answer will help someone else with the same problem.
well all you need to do is to add a file of environment variables locally using this composer command:
`composer dump-env dev` then it will create a file `.env.local.php` the final step is to configure the database url with your personal info.
An example:
`'DATABASE_URL' => 'yourSGBD://username:password@127.0.0.1:5432/appName?serverVersion=13&charset=utf8'`.